# How to access data of rate limiters defined in RouteServiceProvider from inside any controller?

Tags: laravel, throttling, rate-limiting

In my `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` I defined a rate limiter:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('auth', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(10)->by($request->ip());
    });
}
```

I added this as middleware to my route. Now, in my custom controller I would like to read the remaining attempts. How do I get this info? I tried using `RateLimiter::limiter` but that returns the callback defined in the `for` method.

web.php routes:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'auth.',], function () {
    Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
    Route::post('authenticate', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('authenticate')->middleware(['throttle:auth']);
});
```

Function in my `AuthController`:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    dd( RateLimiter::limiter('auth')->remaining() ); // callback error
    dd( RateLimiter::remaining('auth') ); // error because I'd have to hardcode the max attempts here
}
```

Comment: Try using `RateLimiter::availableIn('auth')` for get the number of seconds until the "key" is accessible again.

Comment: Try using `RateLimiter::retriesLeft('auth', $maxAttemtps)`: Get the number of retries left for the key.

Comment: @DanielMesa what if I dont know the `$maxAttempts`? I define them in my Provider  already and I only want to know them there.